# Publisher field in Windows Firewall popup

Tags: windows-firewall

Most of the time I've ever gotten this dialog, the Name and Publisher fields have been pretty unhelpful.  So having our own app list "Main" as the Name and "Unknown" as the Publisher doesn't really seem surprising, but I'd like to know how we can actually specify these fields.

[image: Example firewall prompt with unhelpful Name and Publisher]

I know that it's possible ([one example](http://www.windows7taskforce.com/thumb/firewall%20allow%20program.png/x/560)), but I can't seem to find anything, which might be a side-effect of not knowing what to search for that won't just bring up completely unrelated articles about the firewall in general.  I don't care about stopping it, or manually adding exceptions, I just want to make the dialog more helpful for our app.

I know it's not related to digital signatures, as whether it's signed or not doesn't change it at all.  Is it something in the manifest?  I can't find a consistent definition of what else goes into a manifest other than dependencies and privileges.  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

As always happens, right after writing up my question, I figure it out.  It's the [VERSIONINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058%28VS.85%29.aspx) junk in the resource file, or from within the Visual Studio resource view, add a new Version resource and set the various fields within it.  I've always avoided embedded resources apart from icons, but in this case it seems unavoidable.

Answer (score 2):

After many a trial & error - and plenty misinformation:

In order to change the Publisher from *Unknown* to *your Company's name*, you need the following line in your RC file in the `BLOCK "StringFileInfo"`:

```
VALUE "Publisher", "My Company"
```

Comment: I have a exe and cant rebuild any more. This tool(https://github.com/electron/rcedit) helps me to modify the resource of this exe.
After my try and error, not only fill the Publisher item but the CompanyName also be filled. This is the comand:
```
rcedit-x86.exe ./myprogram.exe --set-version-string "CompanyName" "MyCompany"
```